# Display / print all rows of a tibble (tbl_df)

Tags: r, dplyr

`tibble` (previously `tbl_df`) is a version of a data frame created by the `dplyr` data frame manipulation package in R. It prevents long table outputs when accidentally calling the data frame.

Once a data frame has been wrapped by `tibble`/`tbl_df`, is there a command to view the whole data frame though (all the rows and columns of the data frame)?

If I use `df[1:100,]`, I will see all 100 rows, but if I use `df[1:101,]`, it will only display the first 10 rows. I would like to easily display all the rows to quickly scroll through them.

Is there either a dplyr command to counteract this or a way to unwrap the data frame?

Comment: `View` is unchanged with `"tbl_df"` objects.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Viewing is different than printing.

Answer (score 314, accepted):

You could also use

```
print(tbl_df(df), n=40)
```

or with the help of the pipe operator

```
df %>% tbl_df %>% print(n=40)
```

To print all rows specify `tbl_df %>% print(n = Inf)`

edit 31.07.2021:
**in > dplyr 1.0.0**

```
Warning message:
`tbl_df()` was deprecated in dplyr 1.0.0.
Please use `tibble::as_tibble()` instead.
```

`df %>% as_tibble() %>% print(n=40)`

Comment: if you want don't want to worry about the value of `n` and you're already piping, you can use `df %>% tbl_df %>% print(n = nrow(.))`

Comment: Extending @BLT's answer, you can set `n = Inf` to print all rows.

Comment: `print` (with a tibble) also has the `width = ` and `n_extra = ` options to control how many columns are printed, either directly or indirectly.

Comment: @ClaytonJY I've also found `tbl_df %>% print(n = Inf)` to work for this.

Comment: does anybody know why`print(n = ...)` turns on scientific notation in the tibble display?

Comment: bear in mind that if you choose to do `print(n=nrow(.))`, you need to have an object in hand first; if you are retrieving data from remote data source (e.g. a database connection), you'll have to do `df <- tbl(conn, "db_name"); df %>% print(n=nrow(.))`.

Answer (score 103):

You can use `as.data.frame` or `print.data.frame`.

If you want this to be the default, you can change the value of the `dplyr.print_max` option.

```
options(dplyr.print_max = 1e9)
```

Comment: After running this code, do you know how to disable it? Thanks.

Comment: @ahbon Run `options(dplyr.print_max=NULL)` (this is the default value for this option)

Answer (score 85):

The [tibble vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html) has an updated way to change its default printing behavior:

> You can control the default appearance with options:
>
> `options(pillar.print_max = n, pillar.print_min = m)`: if there are more than n rows, print only the first m rows. Use options(pillar.print_max = Inf) to always show all rows.

> `options(pillar.width = n)`: use n character slots horizontally to show the data. If n > getOption("width"), this will result in multiple tiers. Use `options(pillar.width = Inf)` to always print all columns, regardless of the width of the screen.

**examples**

This will always print all rows:

```
options(pillar.print_max = Inf)
```

This will not actually limit the printing to 50 lines:

```
options(pillar.print_max = 50)
```

But this will restrict printing to 50 lines:

```
options(pillar.print_max = 50, pillar.print_min = 50)
```

Comment: This will change the default behavior for all tibbles. I was looking for a way to override the default constraint. `print(n=100)` appears to do what I want. (Summary tables from `count()`, for example, should display in their entirety, whereas I do want my data tables to be truncated.)

Comment: @dannid looks like you want the accepted answer, then.

Comment: "As of tibble 3.1.0, printing is handled entirely by the pillar package." (From the "Printing tibbles" help file.) To control the default appearance with options you can use: `options(pillar.print_max = n, pillar.print_min = m)`.

Comment: @petzi amazing, thanks for flagging. I believe I've updated it to reflect the latest in the tibble vignette.

Answer (score 8):

As detailed out in the [bookdown documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#data-frame-printing), you could also use a paged table

```
mtcars %>% tbl_df %>% rmarkdown::paged_table()
```

This will paginate the data and allows to browse all rows and columns (unless configured to cap the rows). Example:

[image]

Comment: As described in that documentation: If the paged table is generated by a code chunk in an R Notebook, you can add the parameter `rows.print=[n]` to the chunk options to control the number of rows displayed per page.

Comment: This is great for `html` output, but obviously won't work for `pdf`.

Answer (score 3):

you can print it in Rstudio with View() more convenient:

```
df %>% View()

View(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to turn the tibble to data.frame. It shows everything and you're done

```
df %>% data.frame
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pipes and find yourself wanting to see the whole tibble a lot, here's a solution with a function showAll():

```
showAll<-function(tbl_df){
  print(tbl_df,n=nrow(tbl_df))
}

require(tibble)
#Truncated tibble (default)
mtcars %>% as_tibble()

#Full size tibble
mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% showAll()
```

Comment: The really useful nugget in the center of that is the n argument to the print function.

Comment: I'm not a fan of introducing trivial functions when a function (print n=) already exists.

Comment: the point of this is to avoid having to know how many rows there are