# head() function in R package dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a minor issue but in R when you type `head(data.frame)` you get the first few records from all the columns displayed. In the `dplyr` package the head function has been altered to only show the columns that can fit in your console window. This is often nice, but often I want to see the first few records for all the columns. Is there a way to tell head (in `dplyr`) to show all columns without converting the `tbl.df`/`data.frame` to a `data.frame` (and I prefer `head` to `str()`).

Thanks!

ZR

Comment: dplyr has a head function?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188900/view-entire-dataframe-when-wrapped-in-tbl-df/23189030#23189030

Comment: @Henrik, are you sure that works on columns as well?

Comment: @Arun, I am far from sure. I just posted it as a potentially relevant post in this context. I should have been more explicit about my intention. Thanks for pointing this out Arun!

Comment: @ZRoss `dplyr` v0.2 has the `glimpse()` verb precisely for this.

Comment: In my RProfile.site I have `library(dplyr);head <- glimpse`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can now use the `glimpse()` verb in dplyr 0.2 :

from https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/releases :

> "*`glimpse()` makes it possible to see all the columns in a tbl,
>   displaying as much data for each variable as can be fit on a single line.*"

Comment: glimpse() is good and get's the answer (though I'm more used to the head() style orientation and prefer head() to str()). In answer to the question about creating my own function -- absolutely this is a good approach. But I often teach R and find that my little personal functions would find their way into lecture notes so I prefer to use functions from existing packages if possible. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3):

As Arun said, it's because of the print.tbl_df method.
Just do:

```
print.data.frame(head(your_dplyr_dataframe))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Perhaps I should have clarified this. But the the head() function is useful because it's a super quick way to view the data. head(data) and you're done. But if I have to type print.data.frame(head(dplyr_df)) each time it defeats the purpose. I can definitely do head(data.frame(dplyr_df)) but this is too much typing. I thought maybe that Hadley had included some kind of head(dplyr_df, inclCol=T). I guess not?

Answer (score 3):

To control how many columns are displayed, explicitly call `print()`, setting the `tibble.width` argument.

```
print(yourdataframe, tibble.width = Inf)
```

To allow this for every tibble that you print, set the `tibble.width` global option.

```
options(tibble.width = Inf)
```

See [`?print.tbl_df`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/topics/print.tbl_df) for more information.

Comment: This actually directly answers the question

Answer (score 2):

Why not just define your own `head`-type function. I use this one.  It's been adjusted for a `data.table`.  This way, you can look at whatever you want.  The first 3 rows are set as a default to save space.

```
 peek <- function(d, x = ncol(d))
 {
     if (is.data.table(d)) d[1:3, 1:x, with = FALSE]
     else if (is.data.frame(d) | is.matrix(d)) d[1:3, 1:x] 
 }   ## note the 3 row default (to save space below)
```

On a `data.table`:

```
> library(data.table)
> emteecars <- as.data.table(mtcars)

> peek(emteecars, 5)
#     mpg cyl disp  hp drat
# 1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90
# 2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90
# 3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85

> peek(emteecars)
#     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Now on a `data.frame`:

```
> peek(mtcars)
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1

> peek(as.matrix(mtcars), 2)
#                    mpg cyl
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6
# Datsun 710        22.8   4
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also just assign head(data) to a variable, should remain a tbl_df

```
test <- head(data)
```

Won't show up in console window but might be useful for your purposes