# How to use top_n for conditional extraction

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, top-n

So I have a column (category) that contains either "Yes" or "No" in my df and in order to create a more balanced sample I want to select the rows with the first 500 cases of "Yes" and the first 500 cases of "No" from my dataset.

I've tried this code:

`top_n(df,500, category=="Yes")`

But this select ALL cases of yes instead of only the first 500
I also tried this but this gave me an error though I'm sure it makes no sense

`df %>% filter(top_n(500, category == "Yes") & top_n(500, category=="No"))`
I need a bit of help with the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably just use `head` for this, and filter directly on the data frame

```
df1 <- head(df[df$category == "Yes",], 500)
df2 <- head(df[df$category == "No",], 500)

# to combine
out <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

I'm guessing `top_n` does something similar. I expect there is a nicer way with `dplyr` but this should work :)

Comment: This works great! Just wanted to find a way to get top_n to work or any other dplyr way. Will keep searching :)

Comment: `top_n` doesn't do what you think. If you search `?top_n` in the console, it's finding the top 500 rows, by value. This is important as if you only have one value in the dataset, then selecting 1 row will have the same effect as selecting 5 eg `top_n(data.frame(x=rep(1,10)), 5, "x")` is the same as `top_n(data.frame(x=rep(1,10)), 10, "x")`

Comment: There is a `dplyr` version of `head` called `glimpse` eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408510/head-function-in-r-package-dplyr

Answer (score 0):

If you want to randomly select yes/no answers you can use this code:

```r
#// generate toy data
df <- data.frame(YN = rep(c("yes", "no"),10), val = runif(20, 1, 100))
head(df)
#>    YN      val
#> 1 yes 26.00628
#> 2  no 98.34237
#> 3 yes 68.05788
#> 4  no 21.87011
#> 5 yes 33.92545
#> 6  no 68.74417

#// set random seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

#// randomly sample 5 'yes' answers
yes <- df[sample(which(df$YN == "yes"), 5),]
#// randomly sample 5 'no' answers
no <-  df[sample(which(df$YN == "no"), 5),]

#// create new dataframe with sampled answers
df_sub <- rbind(yes, no)
df_sub
#>     YN       val
#> 5  yes 33.925453
#> 19 yes 53.548253
#> 3  yes 68.057878
#> 15 yes 51.029700
#> 11 yes 91.768337
#> 10  no 11.923457
#> 8   no  8.467184
#> 12  no 63.233610
#> 16  no 93.375332
#> 2   no 98.342369
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! But I wanted to create a "balanced" sample based on the first 500 observations of "yes" and "no", so not random, but thanks anyway for the nice example!

Comment: The balance comes in by sampling identical numbers for yes and no (the number 5 in the `sample` call in the example -- you would chose 500). If there is a bias in how your answers are arranged then by taking the first answers that match your search criteria you may introduce that bias in your subset and not achieving a balanced set. But you surely know your data better than anybody.