# dplyr::tbl_df fill whole screen

Tags: r, dplyr

`dplyr::as.tbl(mtcars)` only fills 10 rows of the screen, as in screenshot below:

[image]

Can R be configured so that if a `tbl_df` can fill the whole R window without any data 'falling off the window' (as in the case of `mtcars`), then `dplyr` will force the `tbl_df` to fill the whole window.

So I want to the output of `dplyr::as.tbl(mtcars)` to be:

[image]

Comment: According to http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/01/09/dplyr-0-4-0/ `options(dplyr.print_max) is now 20, so dplyr will never print more than 20 rows of data (previously it was 100). The best way to see more rows of data is to use View().`

Comment: You may try `options(dplyr.print_max = 1e4)`

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188900/view-entire-dataframe-when-wrapped-in-tbl-df

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several ways to accomplish this:

```
# show up to 1000 rows and all columns *CAPITAL V in View*
df %>% View()

# set option to see all columns and fewer rows
options(dplyr.width = Inf, dplyr.print_min = 6)

# reset options to defaults (or just close R)
options(dplyr.width = NULL, dplyr.print_min = 10)

# for good measure, don't forget about glimpse()...
df %>% glimpse()
```

Comment: I wonder…can anyone provide a function that will print the entire `tbl_df` object if the entire `tbl_df` object will fill the entire R window?