# R: dplyr tally() shows only the frequency of the first 10 factors

Tags: r, statistics, dplyr

I am trying to get the count of 27 factors using tally():

`tally(group_by(export_all, estacion), sort = TRUE)`

The output only shows the first ten factors. dplyr documentation doesn't show the option to see all of them.

My output:

```
     estacion      n
     (fctr)  (int)
1     87344 138883
2     87418 138877
3     87166 138869
4     87311 138864
5     87155 138857
6     87097 138850
7     87047 138844
8     87046 138822
9     87121 138809
10    87453 138743
..      ...    ...
```

I know that all 27 factors have observations.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188900/view-entire-data-frame-when-wrapped-in-tbl-df). If you want, you can do the same job with the forcats package: `export_all$estacion %>% fct_count(sort = TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks. @vincent-zoonekynd answers my question there. I was searching exclusively for tapply answers before posting. My fault.

Comment: Try storing the result in variable and printing it, either using simple pint or for loop