# How to view all rows of an output thats not in table form

Tags: r

**Problem**
I started with an ungrouped data set which I proceeded to group, the output of the grouping however, does not return all 427 rows. The output is needed to input that data into a table.

So initially the data was ungrouped and appears as follows:

```
Occupation Education Age Died
1  household Secondary  39   no
2    farming   primary  83  yes
3    farming   primary  60  yes
4    farming   primary  73  yes
5    farming Secondary  51   no
6    farming iliterate  62  yes
```

The data is then grouped as follows:

```
occu %>% group_by(Occupation, Died, Age) %>% count()##use this to group on the occupation of the suicide victimrs
```

which gives the following output:

```
 Occupation       Died    Age     n
  <fct>            <fct> <int> <int>
1 business/service no       20     2
2 business/service no       30     1
3 business/service no       31     2
4 business/service no       34     1
5 business/service no       36     2
6 business/service no       41     1
7 business/service no       44     1
8 business/service no       46     1
9 business/service no       84     1
10 business/service yes      21     1
# ... with 417 more rows
```

problem is i need all the rows in order to input the grouped data into a table using:

```
dt <- read.table(text="full output from above")
```

If any more code would be useful to solving this let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want, could you add the output you want please?

Comment: Can't you apply `as.table()` to you `occu... ` line?  No need to print to console and read again, r hopefully is smarter ;)

Comment: So i'd like the exact same output given above but with all 417 rows if possible

Comment: It is a print options output.  It can be changed in the options for tibble printing.   Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188900/display-print-all-rows-of-a-tibble-tbl-df)

Comment: so ive tried using as.table () and get the following error: Error in 
    as.table.default(occu %>% group_by(Occupation, Died, Age) %>%  : 
     cannot coerce to a table

Comment: Could you not simply do ``as.data.frame``? Otherwise if you really want to print all the table in the console, follow Akrun's link.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear what you want but try the following code :

```
occu %>% group_by(Occupation, Died, Age) %>% count()
dt <- as.data.frame(occu)
```

It seems you simply want to convert the `tibble` to a `data frame`. There is no need to print all the output and then copy-paste it into `read.table()`.

Also if you need you can save your output with `write.table(dt,"filename.txt")`, it will create a `.txt` file with your data.

---

If what you want is really print all the `tibble` output in the console, then you can do the following code, as suggested by **Akrun**'s link :

```
options(dplyr.print_max = 1e9)
```

It will allow R to print the full `tibble` into the console, which I think is not efficient to do what you are asking.